# How can I apply the same action to multiple images in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, batch

In Adobe Lightroom's Develop mode, is it possible to apply an action to multiple images? When I select multiple images (control/shift click), it highlights those images. I then perform an action (such as rotate right), but it only applies it to the first image. Is this a bug or just normal behavior? How would I go about applying the same action (in this case rotate) to multiple images?

I'm running Lightroom 3.3.

Answer (score 5):

When you are in the Library module, you can select multiple photos and apply rotation to all of them at once.

When you move into the Develop module, you are only working with one image.  But after you have made changes, you can click on the Synch button.  This will give you checkboxes of all the settings you can copy (exposure, etc).  Select those you want, click OK, and it will aply them to all the other images.

This is the LR 4 version of the synch settings. I assume LR3 is similar.

[image]

Comment: So why does Lightroom allow multiple selection in the Develop module if actions can only be applied to a single image?

Comment: Adobe Camera Raw is the same.  You can open several images, but you can only view and live changes on one at a time.  I think it's just a design decision on their part. You would typically select similar images, fine tune one of them, then apply the changes to other images.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to be incorrect for LR 3, when I did in Library module is highlight all the photos I wanted to rotate, then I right clicked to get menu options and click on "rotate right" (depending on which way you're trying to rotate).